# PHP get lastInsertId() as an array, and add index for being the same as another array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have 2 `mysql` tables: `factura` and `detallefactura`.

factura has 2 fields:

```
id  
cliente
```

`detallefactura` has 3 fields:

```
id  
fac_id  
tratamiento
```

I want that `fac_id` be `lastInsertId()` of `factura` `(id)`.

My problem is that `tratamiento` is going to have more that one row (what user adds in the form), so must be an array.

The question is, how can I create more than one index in `fac_id` array, to be the same as `tratamiento` array? Now I get:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\noepruebalast\prueba2.php on line 76  


DetalleFacturas Object
(
    [conn:DetalleFacturas:private] => PDO Object
        (
        )

    [table_name:DetalleFacturas:private] => detallefactura
    [id] => 
    [fac_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 75
        )

    [tratamiento] => Array
        (
            [0] => Limpieza
            [1] => Extraer
        ) )
```

I need "another index"  `[1]  => 75`

Here is the example code:

```
<?php

// get database connection
include_once 'config/database.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

class Facturas{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "factura";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $cliente;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

 function create(){

        $query = "INSERT INTO
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                    cliente = :cliente";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(':cliente', $this->cliente);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
$factura = new facturas($db);


class DetalleFacturas{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "detallefactura";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $fac_id;
    public $tratamiento;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }


    function create(){

        $query = "INSERT INTO
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                    fac_id = :fac_id, tratamiento = :tratamiento";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(':fac_id', $fac_ids);
        $stmt->bindParam(':tratamiento', $tratamientos);


        if (is_array($this->tratamiento)) {
            foreach ($this->tratamiento as $clave=> $tratamientos) {
                $fac_ids = $this->fac_id[$clave];
                $stmt->execute();   
            }
        }
    }
}

$detallefactura = new detallefacturas($db);



if ($_POST){
            $factura->cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
            $factura->create();
            $last[] = $db->lastInsertId('factura');

            $detallefactura->fac_id = $last;
            $detallefactura->tratamiento = $_POST['tratamiento'];
            $detallefactura->create();

        } else {

            echo "no va";
        }
?>

<form action='prueba2.php' method='post'>

    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='cliente' class='form-control'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Tratamiento</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='tratamiento[]' class='form-control'></td>
        </tr>

                <tr>
            <td>Tratamiento2</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='tratamiento[]' class='form-control'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Crear</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>

 <pre><?php print_r($detallefactura) ?></pre>
```

Comment: last_insert_id() can only ever return one value. it will not return a series of IDs if you do a series of inserts. you only ever get the **LAST** id generated on a connection. you'd need to insert/get id/insert/get id/etc...

Comment: I only need one value (in this case 75), but i need to copy it so many times as tratamiento array. If tratamiento is an array of 2, I need[fac_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 75  [1] => 75 
        )

Comment: I want a million bucks, dont mean I'm gonna get it, lastinsertid is just that the last insert id, you could select the ids order them  desc...  Or why not return the last insert id from create() and then store that as you insert items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this

> I only need one value (in this case 75), but i need to copy it so many times as tratamiento array. If tratamiento is an array of 2, I need[fac_id] => Array ( [0] => 75 [1] => 75 )

If you really need it that many times then do array_keys and array_fill_keys

```
 $keys = array_keys($tratamiento);
 $fac_id = array_fill_keys( $keys, $insertId );
```

Something like that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

Comment: I´m going to try that.

Comment: Thanks, It works:              
            $detallefactura->fac_id = $last;
            $keys = array_keys($_POST['tratamiento']);
            $detallefactura->fac_id = array_fill_keys( $keys, $last );